# Using multiple conditions (AND) in SASS IF statement

Tags: if-statement, sass

Using SASS, I would like to have multiple condition in IF statement

**What I use right now :**

```
@function color-x ($alpha) {
    @if      $accent == red   {@return red($alpha)} 
    @else if $accent == green {@return green($alpha)} 
    @else if $accent == blue  {@return blue($alpha)}
}
```

**My naive (failed) attempt to use multiple conditions :**

```
@function color-x ($alpha) {
    @if      $accent == red   && theme == light {@return red($alpha)} 
    @else if $accent == green && theme == light {@return green($alpha)} 
    @else if $accent == blue  && theme == light {@return blue($alpha)}
}
```

Is it possible to have multiple conditions?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

From the Sass language reference documentation:

> **Boolean Operations**
>
> SassScript supports `and`, `or`, and `not` operators for boolean values.

[(link)](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#boolean_operations)

So an if statement expression with a compound condition would look like this:

```
@if $var1 == value1 and $var2 == value2 {
    // ...
}
```

Further, parentheses can be used to affect the order of operations in a more complicated expression:

```
@if ($var1 == value1 and not ($var2 == value2)) or ($var3 == value3) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this, the 'and' part must be all lowercase -- using AND (all caps) doesn't work.

Comment: Awesome! (here's an updated Sass documentation link - the one above didn't work for me: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/operators/boolean)

Answer (score 3):

You can also do:

```
@if index("foo" "bar", $value) { .. }
```

Beware though:

1. It might not be quite obvious what you are trying to do.
2. It returns a number or `null`, not a boolean.