# sass mixin parameters - check for patterns

Tags: sass, mixins

How can I check if all parameters passed to a mixin are the same value?

pseudo code:

```
@mixin cols($width...) {
  @if (all $width values are the same) {
    // do something
  }
}

.three-cols {
  @include cols(4,4,4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delegated the task of checking to see if the values are equal to a `function` which can then be called from the `mixin` so that they both have single responsibility.

```
@function check_values($values...) {
  $counter: 0;
  @if ( nth($values, 1) != nth($values,2) ) {
    $counter: 0;
  }
  @else {
    $counter: $counter + 1;
    @for $i from 2 to length($values) {
      $counter: if(nth($values, $i) == nth($values, $i + 1), $counter + 1, $counter );
    }
  }
  @return if($counter + 1 == length($values), true, false)
}
```

The `function` returns either **true** or **false** and can be used on any number of args

```
@debug check_values(2,2,1,1,2,2); //false
@debug check_values(2,2,2); //true
@debug check_values(2,2,2,1); //false
```

The `function` just needs to be called in the `mixin`

```
@mixin cols($width...) {
  @if ( check_values($width...) ) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Sass supports `and`, `or`, and `not` operator for boolean values.

You could do

```
@if ($width_1 == $width_2 and $width_2 == $width_3){
  // do something
}
```

More here: [Using multiple conditions (AND) in SASS IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225229/using-multiple-conditions-and-in-sass-if-statement)